# fake news dataset using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this details to generate a dataset for Facebook fake news detection:

```
Profile parameters (Fake and legitimate): Total number of information 
related to multiple profiles (Facebook)
Total profiles: 5026
Total news collected: 15328
Total number of post: 42256893
Total number followers: 3685643
Total number of followings: 2354782
Total number of likes by the user: 16236669
Total umber of listed count: 67 976
Total URL’s shared: 2609
```

I want to generate a dataset my python code is:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(
columns=['profileid', 'profilename', 'dateofjoin', 'allfriends', 'profilepicture', 'numberofgroupjoins',
         'numberofpagelikes', 'newspost', 'profilewithphotoguard', 'numberofsharedstories', 'numberoffollowers',
         'numberofevents', 'numberofsharedposts (image, text, video)', 'numberofurlshared', 'numberoftags',
         'numberofhashtag', 'numberofnewlyaddedfriends', 'recentpostlikedorshared', 'currentlocation',
         'messageswithspamwords', 'source', 'headline', 'bodytext', 'text', 'images (with text or with hyperlink)',
         'videos', 'linguisticsbased (chapter, word, sentence, document, quoted word, external link, etc.)',
         'StatisticalFeatures (count, ImageRatio, MultiImageRatio, HotImageRatio, ShortImageRatio)',
         'Images (ClaritySource, Coherence, SimilarityDistribution, DiversitySource, ClusteringScore)', 'PostDate'])

# Populate the dataframe with random values

for i in range(15000):
dataset.loc[i] = [np.random.randint(0, high=5000),  # profile id
                  'User' + str(np.random.randint(0, high=5000)),  # profile name
                  np.random.randint(0, high=999999999),  # date of join
                  np.random.randint(0, high=5000),  # all friends
                  np.random.randint(0, high=2),  # profile picture
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of group joins
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of page likes
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # news post
                  np.random.randint(0, high=2),  # profile with photo guard
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of stories shared
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of following
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of events
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of shared posts (image, text, video)
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of URL shared
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of tags
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of hashtags
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # number of newly added friends
                  np.random.randint(0, high=2),  # recent post liked or shared
                  np.random.randint(0, high=2),  # current location
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # messages with spam words
                  np.random.randint(0, high=2),  # source
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # headline
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1000),  # body text
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1),  # text
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1),  # images (with text or with hyperlink)
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1),  # videos
                  np.random.randint(0, high=999999999),  # linguistics based (chapter, word, sentence, document, quoted word, external link, etc.)
                  np.random.randint(0, high=999999999),  # StatisticalFeatures (count, ImageRatio, MultiImageRatio, HotImageRatio, ShortImageRatio)
                  np.random.randint(0, high=1),  # Images (ClaritySource, Coherence, SimilarityDistribution, DiversitySource, ClusteringScore)
                  np.random.randint(0, high=999999999)]  # PostDate
```

1- I dont know how to put a range date between ex; 1970 to 2023 for date of join feature and post date can any one help me for that?
2- another question dose the numbers for all features its seems right or not any idea?

Comment: Are you using Pandas (looks like it): If yes, you might want to consider adding the `pandas` tag to your question. Also: Don't build dataframes like that, do it column-wise by using `np.random.randint`s `size=15_000` keyword argument.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it using the random together with date function. Which is like:

```py
start_date = date(1970...)
end_date = date(2023...)

days_delta = (end_date - start_date).days
random_days_to_append = random.randrange(days_delta)

random_date = start_date + datime.timedelta(random_days_to_append)
```